# string array to be separated with comma

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I had a string array which I want it to be returned in view separated by comma.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => name.studentName) <span>, </span>}
```

I'm using this way but the last string will ended with a comma also. Wondering how to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have a collection of students on your model each possessing a `studentName` property that you want to display:

```
public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
```

And inside your view you are looping through this collection and displaying each student name individually.

Now instead of looping you could do the following:

```
@Html.Raw(
    string.Join(
        "<span>,<span>",
        Model.Students.Select(x => Html.Encode(x.studentName))
    )
)
```

or even better, externalize this logic into a reusable custom HTML helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString FormatStudentNames(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, IEnumerable<Student> students)
    {
        return new HtmlString(
            string.Join(
                "<span>,<span>",
                students.Select(x => Html.Encode(x.studentName))
            )
        );
    }
}
```

and then inside your view simply call this helper:

```
@Html.FormatStudentNames(Model.Students)
```

You no longer need to write any foreach or whatever loops you are writing.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@string.Join(",", name.studentName);
```

And have a look at [string.Join on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(".category").change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        loadSubCategory(value)
    });

    function loadSubCategory(parentID) {

        var $el = $("#SubCats");
        $el.prop("disabled", true);
        $el.empty();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: "/Category/loadSubCategory?id=" + parentID,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != '' && data != null) {
                    if (data != 'error') {
                        var sch = JSON.parse(data);
                        if (sch.length > 0) {
                            $el.prop("disabled", false);
                            for (i = 0; i < sch.length; i++) {
                                $el.append($("<option></option>")
                                    .attr("value", sch[i].ID).text(sch[i].Description));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

public ActionResult loadSubCategory(string id)
        {

            string list = "";
            try
            {

                list = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(menu.SubCategory(id));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return Content(list);

        }
  public List<CategoryModel> SubCategory(string parentID){

     List<CategoryModel> listCategory= new List<CategoryModel>();
      string[] yourValues = parentID.Split(',');
                    foreach (var item in yourValues)
                    {
                        var Category = UowObj.CategoryRepository.Get(filter: c => c.ParentId.ToString() == item && c.IsActive == true).ToList();
                        if (Category != null)
                        {
                            var category= new CategoryModel();
                            foreach (var itemq in Category)
                            {

                                category.ID = itemq.ID;
                                category.Description = itemq.Description;
                            }
                            listCategory.Add(merchant);
                        }

    }
```

Comment: It would help if you'd expand on the code to explain how it answers the question...

Comment: Yeah  ! Please check my Complete code , i hope this code can easily help you.. I just chanege on category Dropdown Value and pas this change value to this ajax call  url: "/Deals/loadSubCategory?id=" + parentID, where parrent id can retrieve Category Id from View. and if u select more then 1 category then string contains more then value and you can seperte this value using comma sepreted form..